# Replace values greater than 0 with column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

There is a dataframe of id's in the rows and columns that represent the number of times a user has visited the website.I would like a daywise view of all the user id's who have visited the website which in turn is represented by all value greater than or equal to 1

Df

```
Codes  2022-09-04  2022-09-03  2022-09-02
A1AA        1           0          0
A1BB        0           0          2
A1CC        5           0          0
A2DD        0           5          0 
A1EE        0           1          0
A1AA        0           0          1
```

Expected Output

```
Dates          Codes

2022-09-04     A1AA
2022-09-04     A1CC
2022-09-03     A2DD
2022-09-03     A1EE
2022-09-02     A1BB
2022-09-02     A1AA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use: [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to benefit with dropping if NA:

```
(df.set_index('Codes')
 .replace(0, pd.NA)
 .rename_axis(columns='Dates').stack()
 .reset_index().drop(columns=0)
)
```

Or with [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), although with a different order (you can `sort_values` if needed):

```
df.melt('Codes', var_name='Date').loc[lambda d: d.pop('value').ne(0)]
```

output:

```
  Codes       Dates
0  A1AA  2022-09-04
1  A1BB  2022-09-02
2  A1CC  2022-09-04
3  A2DD  2022-09-03
4  A1EE  2022-09-03
5  A1AA  2022-09-02
```

Answer (score 2):

Doing `dot`

```
s = df.set_index('Codes')
s = s.gt(0).dot(s.columns).reset_index(name='Dates')
Out[34]: 
  Codes       Dates
0  A1AA  2022-09-04
1  A1BB  2022-09-02
2  A1CC  2022-09-04
3  A2DD  2022-09-03
4  A1EE  2022-09-03
5  A1AA  2022-09-02
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the desired output with the indicated column sequence and row sorting (descending by `Dates`), you can do this:

```py
df = (
    ((df.set_index('Codes') != 0) @ df.columns[1:])
    .reset_index()
    .iloc[:, ::-1]
    .set_axis(['Dates','Codes'], axis=1)
    .sort_values('Dates', ascending=False, ignore_index=True) )
```

Explanation:

- The [`@` operator](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html#pandas.DataFrame.dot) is equivalent to the `dot()` method of DataFrame
- `set_index()` gets the `Codes` column out of the way to perform `dot()` against the remaining column labels in `df`
- `reset_index()` restores `Codes` to a column
- `iloc[]` reverses the column sequence
- `set_axis()` labels the columns as specified in OP
- `sort_values()` puts the dates in descending order.

Output:

```
        Dates Codes
0  2022-09-04  A1AA
1  2022-09-04  A1CC
2  2022-09-03  A2DD
3  2022-09-03  A1EE
4  2022-09-02  A1BB
5  2022-09-02  A1AA
```